# An indefinite integral

Tags: calculus

Finding the indefinite integral of

$$\int \dfrac{dt}{\cos^2{t^4}\sqrt{(9+\tan t)}}$$

I can't seem to figure this one out. Would like some help please!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks pretty ugly.  Just want to confirm that that's $t^4$ rather than a fourth root in the denominator.

Comment: Oh, now that you say that I do think I saw it was t^4 by mistake. I'll try it again. Thank you!

Comment: @Frank Where did you encounter this problem?

Comment: I would be surprised if this has a closed form solution...where did it come up

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that it has a closed-form solution the simplest simplification that you can do is transform to

$$ \int \frac{ \sec^2(t^4)}{\sqrt{ \tan(t) + 9}} dt $$

And I do not think there is a clever substitution on that